# How to add to return VIew?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a View for each method, I have it set the parameter for return in the header, but how do I make VIEW?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.Extensions;
using System;

namespace ProjectAboutProjects
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class FormatReponseFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
    {
        private enum FormatResponseType { Json, Xml, View, Unknown }
        private FormatResponseType _requestedType { get; set; }
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            var _result = (ObjectResult) filterContext.Result;
            switch (_requestedType)
            {
                //https://localhost:44342/api/Post/Search?id=qwe
                case FormatResponseType.Json:
                var data = new { Data = _result.Value };
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult(data);
                break;
                case FormatResponseType.Xml:
                filterContext.Result = new XmlResult(_result.Value);
                break;
                case FormatResponseType.View:
                //filterContext.Result = new ViewResult(_result.Value);// Don't worl(
                break;

                case FormatResponseType.Unknown:
                default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Uknown Content Type ain Accept Header");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** What should `return filterContext.Result = new ViewResult (_result.Value);` in this line to point to View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewResult needs some more data

```
   filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { 
       ViewName = "YourViewName", 
       ViewData = // Create your view data here, might be your result
   }
```

Also try to set the [exception handled attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext.exceptionhandled?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ActionExecutedContext_ExceptionHandled).

```
   filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
```